# ByteBuddy java agent results in noclassdeffound error

Tags: java, sql, classloader, agent, byte-buddy

I get the following error for a simple agent written with Bytebuddy. I have a simple demo application which is spring boot based and trying to run it with a simple java agent code snippet below.

```java
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    System.out.println("Agent Loaded");
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
        .type(hasSuperType(named("javax.sql.DataSource")))
        .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) ->
            builder.visit(
                Advice.to(VariableAdvice.class).on(isMethod())
            )
        )
        .installOn(inst);
}
```

Advice code

```java
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;

public class VariableAdvice {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static void OnEnter() {
        System.out.println("Hello ByteBuddy");
    }
}
```

POM

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```

more

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Premain-Class>com.abc.Agent</Premain-Class>
                        <Agent-Class>com.abc.Agent</Agent-Class>
                        <!-- <Main-Class>com.abc.Agent</Main-Class>-->
                        <Can-Redefine-Classes>true</Can-Redefine-Classes>
                        <Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When in Intellij I get the following error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261_deleteword\bin\java.exe" -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Builder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:327)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 5 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

Comment: I didn't face this kind of an issue with java agent written using asm. I gather, byte buddy developed on top of asm? Appreciate and thanks in advance for a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you create a jar file that contains your classes that is your agent and contains the `premain` method. Since you are using Maven, your project dependencies will by default not be contained in this created jar file.

You will need to create a *fat jar* ("*uber jar*") that also contains Byte Buddy where Maven offers the [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time with this, in my earlier asm module, the classes were packaged together. Didn't check this part for bytebuddy. It works now.